# Recognizing date strings in Perl

Tags: perl, date, parsing

I have a script that is processing a lot of data.  Some of the data fields coming in are dates or timestamps.

When I run into a date/timestamp I need to convert it from the local time to GMT.  Obviously I don't want to attempt this conversion if the field is not a date or timestamp.  The problem is, I don't know what format the date or timestamp field will have.

---

[`Scalar::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) has a [`looks_like_number`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#looks_like_number) function to determine whether a variable "Looks like a number".  Is there any equivalent function for recognizing dates or timestamps?

Comment: Check out https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thinking about the general case - there's just an awful lot of different possible ways you can write a date. That's why most systems just don't, and use a numeric timecode internally, and format date on request.

Not least amongst these is the implicit ambiguity of the digits - by convention US date formats are month/day, but a lot of the rest of the world use day/month.

However, the approach I'd probably go with is - given you *do* have fields you're trying to process - use something like `strptime` to parse the date to a time stamp, validate the timestamp (e.g. is it 'sensible' given the data) and if it is, assume that was corrrect.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my @formats = ( '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', '%d %b %y', );

my @example_strs = ( '14 Oct 15', '2014/08/22 17:42:33', 'bogus' );


foreach my $example_str (@example_strs) {
    my $timestamp; 
    foreach my $format (@formats) {
        if ( not defined $timestamp 
             and $timestamp =
            eval { localtime->strptime( $example_str, $format ) } )
        {
            print "$example_str converted to $timestamp using $format\n";
        }
    }
    print "Couldn't parse $example_str" unless $timestamp;
}
```

You could also add some range checking on `$timestamp` to ensure the date is sane.

e.g.

```
if ( $timestamp < time() - 365 * 60 * 60 
  or $timestamp > time() + 84700 )  {
   #assume it's invalid. 
}
```

This'll work for integer validation too - but if your integer values are close enough to `time()` it's impossible to tell the difference. (And statistically speaking it's likely to be keyed to time if it is in that range)

But have a bit of a flick through [`strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) to see how many formatting options there are.

Comment: That's very close to what I need, the problem is that some of the fields are simple integer values and this recognizes them as being valid timestamps.

Comment: Well, integers are either easy or hard. If they're numerically similar to `time()` then there's just no way to tell if it's an integer the represents the time, or an integer that doesn't. However you can probably just assume that any value `< time() - 365 * 24 * 60 * 60` is just a number.

Comment: @Sobrique, the `Time::Piece->strptime()` call should be replaced with `localtime->strptime()`.  `Time::Piece->strptime()` parses dates/times in the UTC/GMT time zone.

Comment: @Sobrique I think you might mean `or` instead of `and` in your last if statement.  Also is there any particular reason you're using `and` instead of `&&`?

Comment: Yes, you're quite right. That should have been an `or`. And I'm using the word version, because I think it clearer, rather than any specific reason here. (In general, I prefer `or` unless I need `||` because of precedence).